# Javascript - how to capitalize key.value within an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

How do I capitalize the first letter of each contact's first name?

```
 String.prototype.capitalize = function (string) { return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);}

 var contactList = {};

 contactList.bobSmith = {
 firstName: "bob",
 lastName: "smith",
 location: "new york"
};

contactList.johnDoe = {
 firstName: "john",
 lastName: "doe",
 location: "san francisco"
};

var contact2 = contactList["johnDoe"].firstName;
contact1.capitalize();
contact2.capitalize();
console.log(contact1 + " " + contact2);
```

I get an error message that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined".

Comment: You get the error, because the function expects an argument to be passed (`string`), but you don’t pass anything in `contact1.capitalize()` and `contact2.capitalize()`. Therefore `string` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

`function () { return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);}`

Answer (score 2):

Your `String.prototype.capitalize` function requires an argument `string` which you're not passing to it when called.  I'd recommend avoiding adding methods to the `String.prototype` and just use a stand-alone function instead...

```
function capitalise(str) {
  return str.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

contact2 = capitalise(contact2);
//=> "John"
```

...or if you're looking to capitalise the value in the contactList object, then just...

```
contactList.johnDoe.firstName = capitalise(contact2);
```

Hope that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make it a habit of popping methods into prototype. It's frowned upon because future versions of JavaScript could come out and put a method with the same name in the prototype and you would be screwed.

I didn't write it this way but you could put the capitalize function on to the contactList object and you would basically achieve the same thing your trying to do with the prototype.

```
var contactList = {};

 contactList.names =[
{
 firstName: "bob",
 lastName: "smith",
 location: "new york"
},
{
 firstName: "john",
 lastName: "doe",
 location: "san francisco"
}];

function capitalizeName(name) {
    var strCap = name[0].toUpperCase();
    var tailTxt = name.substr(1, name.length);
    fullTxt = strCap + tailTxt;
    return fullTxt;
)

$.each( contactList.names, function(i){
    capitalizeName(contactList.names[i].firstName);
});
```